# How to deal with large amount of data in Python

Tags: python, text-files, histogram, large-data

I have a textfile with large amount of data (3 GB). Each line of this textfile contains time, source IP, destination IP and size. As you know the digits in the last section of IP address shows port address. I want to bring those port addresses to a histogram which I did it for 10 000 lines of data but as I could guess the Python code cannot be executed for that large amount of data. I briefly explain the code I have written. First I read that 10 000 data point, later I split them and put all in a list named as everything_list. Just ignore the condition that while loop works. Later I put all the port addresses in a list and draw the histogram of those.
Now suppose I have a million of data lines, I cannot read them in the first place let alone to categorize them. Some people told me to use arrays and some told me to process a chunk of data and after that process another chunk of data. I am confused with all people said. Can anybody help me with this issue?

```
text_file = open("test.data", "r")
a = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

everything_list = a.split()
source_port_list = []
i=0
while 6+7*i<len(everything_list):

    source_element = everything_list[2+7*i]
    source_port_position = source_element.rfind('.')
    source_port_number = int(source_element[source_port_position + 1:])
    source_port_list.append(source_port_number)

    i=i+1


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab


numBins = 20
plt.hist(source_port_list, numBins, color='red', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

This is the lines format:

```
15:42:42.719063 IP 129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674: tcp 1460
15:42:42.719205 IP 129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674: tcp 1460
15:42:42.719209 IP 129.63.57.175.45241 > 62.85.5.142.55455: tcp 0
15:42:42.719213 IP 24.34.41.8.1236 > 129.63.1.23.443: tcp 394
15:42:42.719217 IP 59.167.148.152.25918 > 129.63.57.40.36075: tcp 0
15:42:42.719260 IP 129.63.223.16.2823 > 80.67.87.25.80: tcp 682
15:42:42.719264 IP 129.63.184.118.2300 > 64.111.215.46.80: tcp 0
15:42:42.719269 IP 129.63.184.118.2300 > 64.111.215.46.80: tcp 0
```

Comment: how much ram you have would decide how much you can store in memory, also the last digits in an actual ip have nothing to do with a port

Comment: can you dump some lines of your source file, to get the exact structure?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he meant `127.0.0.1:8080` for instance

Comment: @Jivan, but `source_port_position + 1` is not going to find it, for instance `10.10.10.10:22`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I totally agree. That's why I'd like to see the source :)

Comment: Anyway reading the whole file into memory is the wrong approach, iterate over the file object and parse line by line, that will save a couple of gig straight away

Comment: The lines are like this:15:42:42.719063 IP 129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674: tcp 1460
15:42:42.719205 IP 129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674: tcp 1460

Comment: @PadraicCunningham My RAM is about 24Gb.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are definitly right about reading the whole data.

Comment: Also consider with that many data points, the resolution of the graph is most likely going to be restricted by the number of pixels in the graph. Each pixel being a point of resolution, or a little box that contains some sort of density/average, so it might not even be necessary to plot every point. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data

Comment: I think if you just loop over the file object a lot of your problems will be gone. can you add a snippet of the file exactly as is to your question, it is hard to see the actual format in your comment

Comment: You actually store the whole file with read and then store all the contents again using split

Comment: what do you want from `15:42:42.719063 IP 129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674: tcp 1460`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I want to see have the histogram of port addresses or sizes.

Comment: I mean which just port  `47843` or what exact data are you trying to extract?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Yeah, just those port addresses.

Comment: but just the first ip port or both as your code suggests a src which I presume is the first?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I am not sure I understand your question!

Comment: you have two ip's `129.241.138.133.47843 > 129.63.27.12.2674` do you want both ports or just the first

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Just first one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the data looks like, but I think the issue is that you try to hold it all in memory at once. You need to do it little by little, [read the lines one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009882/how-to-read-large-file-line-by-line-in-python) and build the histogram as you go.

```
histogram = {}
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        ip = ...
        if ip in histogram:
            histogram[ip] += 1
        else:
            histogram[ip] = 1
```

You can now plot the histogram, but use `plt.plot` not `plt.hist` since you already have the frequencies in the `histogram` dictionary.

Comment: a defaultdict would be better

Comment: Interesting. There's also a Counter dictionary [in there](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). For me, sometimes simplicity trumps performance though.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting the whole code? Since I am a new python user I do not know how to exert these changes!

Comment: Oops, last line was wrong, fixed now. What it does is iterate through the lines, keeping a count on how many times it has seen a given ip. The histogram dictionary has for keys the ips and for values the corresponding counts. The last line simply starts the count for the ip at 1, and the other branch of the if statement increments the count for the ip it has found on that line. How to take the ip from the line is described in the other answers. I left it as `ip = ...` for you to fill in

Comment: Don't mind the first two comments. They are just posible performance improvements using other data structures for the result

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex and compile it **outside** your loop.

Altogether with reading your file in **lazy** mode, line by line.

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

r = re.compile(r'(?<=\.)[0-9]{2,5}(?= \>)')
ports = []

for line in open("test.data", "r"):
    ports.append(re.search(r, line).group(0))

# determines the number of lines you want to take into account
i = (len(ports) - 6) // 7

# keeps only the first i elements
ports = ports[0:i]

numBins = 20
plt.hist(ports, numBins, color='red', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

This code takes into account the fact that you want only the `(n-6) / 7` first items, `n` being the number of lines of your source file. Try with some `+1/-1` if it's not totally accurate. Getting rid of the unwanted items at the end allows your loop not to be bothered with checking a condition on each iteration.

**EDIT:**

You can combine several things above to get a more concise and efficient code:

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

r = re.compile(r'(?<=\.)[0-9]{2,5}(?= \>)')

ports = [ re.search(r, line).group(0) for line in open("test.data", "r") ]
ports = ports[0:(len(ports) - 6) // 7]

numBins = 20
plt.hist(ports, numBins, color='red', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

If you think your list of ports will be too large to fit in RAM (which I find unlikely), my advice would be to use a dict of ports:

```
ports = {}
for line in open("test.data", "r"):
    port = re.search(r, line).group(0)
    if not ports.get(port, False):
        ports[port] = 0
    ports[port] += 1
```

Which will give you something like:

```
>>> ports
{
    "8394": 182938,
    "8192": 839288,
    "1283": 9839
}
```

Note that in such a case, your call to `plt.hist` will have to be modified.

Comment: But the point is, I will have a long list of ports which I might not have enough RAM capacity to store all.

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul, you would want a serious amount of data to use all 24 gigs of ram

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul you could put them in a dictionary where keys are port number and values are the number of ports found - which would save you tons of space potentially

Comment: @Jivan, as far as I know if I want to do this, I should not do it by hist because hist takes all data and then plot it. I should do this by processing a chunk of data and after that another chunk and ...

Comment: @Jivan about 2 or 3 million port addresses.

Comment: :@Jivan, `my_list[n:]` actually returns from n to the end not up to n

Comment: @Jivan regular expressions are cached in Python. Compiling it outside the loop shouldn't make much of a difference in speed (though it can be used to improve readability). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/452143/1935144.

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul an integer takes let's say 2 bytes. A string 4n bytes, n being the length of the string. So let's say 18 bytes per port. Which gives approx. 54Mb. Let's triple this for other stuff, and my guess is that 2 or 3 million ports will easily fit into 24Gb of RAM.

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul ok. Knowing that, I advise you to keep with the list method, so that you can use it to call `plt.hist` as before

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul any follow-up?

Comment: @Jivan, Thank you, that was incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and a defaultdict which will be more efficient:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
with open("a_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
         d[line.split()[2].rsplit(".",1)[-1]] += 1 
print(d)

defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1236': 1, '2300': 1, '47843': 2, '45241': 1, '25918': 1, '2823': 1})
```

Might also be worth checking out different ways to plot, matplotlib is not the most efficient:

[pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/), [guiqwt](https://pythonhosted.org/guiqwt/reference.html#module-guiqwt.pyplot), [gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This `split` method is more efficient but I personally find it less readable and less maintainable than a regex.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how much more efficient? Like, say for 3M lines?

Comment: well parsing a string is 3-4 times faster using the split method, i could probably make it more efficient I have not looked into it too much, I would actually probably use pandas myself to do what the OP wants

Comment: I would too, would definitely be a lot faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be iterating by line and using regex to find the port. Try something like this:

```
import re

ports = []
with open("path/to/your/text/file.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ports.append(re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d+)", line))
        # that regex explained:
        # # re.compile(r"""
        # #     \d{1,3}\.       # 1-3 digits followed by a literal .
        # #     \d{1,3}\.       # 1-3 digits followed by a literal .
        # #     \d{1,3}\.       # 1-3 digits followed by a literal .
        # #     \d{1,3}\.       # 1-3 digits followed by a literal .
        # #     (               # BEGIN CAPTURING GROUP
        # #       \d+           #   1 or more digits
        # #     )               # END CAPTURING GROUP""", re.X)
```

This is assuming your IP/port is formatted as you explain in your comment

```
IP.IP.IP.IP.PORT
```

Comment: `_ ,port = line.rsplit(".",1)` would be a lot better, I don't think this is really the issue though

Comment: @PadraicCunningham certainly the problem is `a = text_file.read()`, but I prefer using regex in instances like this: not the least bit because there are two ports in each line, and OP's code will only find one of them.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting the whole code? Since I am a new python user I do not know how to exert these changes! BTW I do not know what does the last line of your code does!

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul I edited with an extended definition of the regex. It basically finds anything that looks like the IP addresses in your logs (1-3 digits four times, separated by dots) then separates the port numbers and saves them in a list. I can't actually rewrite your code because I don't know anything about matplotlib, so I don't know what that is doing vs. what it might be able to do better !:)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an immediate response to your question, but as being new to python there is a nice Coursera course dealing with that very subject. "Programming for Everybody (Python)" it is free to take and wont use too much of your time. the course starts February 2 2015.  Also the text book "Python for Informatics: Exploring Information" is a Free Creative Commons  download. at http://www.pythonlearn.com/book.php   I hope this helps.