# Plotting millions of data points in Python?

Tags: python, plot, large-data

I have written a complicated code. The code produces a set of numbers which I want to plot them. The problem is that I cannot put those numbers in a list since there are `2 700 000 000` of them.
So I need to plot one point then produce second point (the first point is replaced by second point so the first one is erased because I cannot store them). These numbers are generated in different sections of the code so I need to hold (MATLAB code) the figure. 
For making it more conceivable to you, I write a simple code here and I want you to show me how to plot it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
j=10
while i<2700000000:
    plt.stem(i, j, '-')
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 2
plt.show()
```

Suppose I have billions of `i` and `j`!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Which of your 2.7 billion points do you wish to plot?

Comment: I believe you should be able to plot 2.7 billion points. Keeping it in a list may not feasible, but you could use a generator if you are computing the values on the fly.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth suppose i starts from zero to 2.7 billion **x-axis** and j is generated numbers which has different values **y-axis**

Comment: @Bair, I am not computing the values on the fly. And I already tried and could not put all in the list. I do not have enough memory.

Comment: I wrote that simple code to give you some understanding of what I'm doing. Even that code is not being processed. Just the first point is being plotted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data

Comment: Who can revise that above-mentioned code?

Comment: If you really must plot them all (why not bin them down to 2.7 million, or fewer, for example?) I would consider generating a large series of PIL images and altering the colours of individual pixels. You could stitch or scale the images afterwards if that was required.

Comment: @jozzas actually the bin numbers are 2.7 billion but I want to sketch it with stem

Comment: have you tried graphlab (graphlab.org)? it should be able to handle that amount of data, and plot them.

Comment: @adrianX thanks for introducing something new. I should try that graphlab.org

Comment: What sort of billion X billion pixel resolution device are you going to plot these numbers on ? There is going to have to be some downsampling somewhere in the processing chain. You can either do it explicitly yourself, or you can find a better graphic library that does it for you. ( See @dstromberg 's link above, maybe. )

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
j=10
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca()
while i<10000: # Fewer points for speed.
    ax.stem([i], [j]) # Need to provide iterable arguments to ax.stem
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 2
fig.show()
```

generates the following figure:
[image]
Isn't this what you're trying to achieve? After all the input numbers aren't stored anywhere, just added to the figure as soon as they are generated. You don't really need Matlab's `hold` equivalent, the figure won't be shown until you call `fig.show()` or `plt.show()` to show the current figure.

Or are you trying to overcome the problem that you can' hold the `matplotlib.figure` in your RAM? In which case my answer doesn't answer your question. Then you either have to save partial figures (only parts of the data) as pictures and combine them, as suggested in the comments, or think about an alternative way to show the data, as suggested in the other answer.