# How to port simple spatial index using SQLite R-Trees to Postgres?

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, spatial-query, r-tree

I have implemented a simple spatial indexing schema based on bounding boxes by following the SQLite R*Tree [tutorial](https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html), which has given me the following schema:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE events_region USING rtree(
    id,              -- primary key
    xmin, xmax,      -- minimum and maximum X coordinate
    ymin, ymax,      -- minimum and maximum Y coordinate
);
```

I want to now port this schema to Postgres (but not using PostGIS in order to cut down on dependencies). I know that this should be possible using a GIST index (as R-trees have been phased out, with GIST now filling their role), but I'm struggling to work out how to go about this.

Comment: If PostGIS solves your problem, then why don't you use it? Just set it up when you install Postgres. It's a one time thing.

Comment: So, you want a [`gist`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html) index on a [`box`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) column/expression? Have you tried [`box_ops`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html)? Of course, for more advanced indexing/searching I also recommend PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with points rather than boxes:

```
time psql -c 'create table t(p point)'
time psql -c "insert into t select (point(
  '(' || generate_series || ',' || generate_series || ')')
) from generate_series(1, 10000000)"
time psql -c 'create index on t using gist(p)'
time psql -c "select count(*) from t
  where p <@ box '(1000000,1000000),(9000000,2000000)'"
```

This creates a line of 10m points, and queries the count of points within the box with lower left (x=1m, y=1m) and upper right (x=9m, y=2m):

```
  count  
---------
 1000001
(1 row)
```

Index creation took 100s on my SSD, which a bit sad. But well. Query was 0.2, but this was bound by iterating a bunch of data, query with `limit 100` on empty region was 0.035s which is good, it is definitely being accelerated.

`point` is a type on itself as listed at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html. I don't see how to create spatial indexes on pre-existing integer columns which is a shame.

The weird operator `<@` means "contained in". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-geometry.html documents some of the other weird geometric operators, and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/gist-builtin-opclasses.html lists which geometric types support what.

To more closely match the SQLite schema, you would want to setup the database with `box` types instead of `point` types, and then determine the correct weird operator of choice, likely either `<@` or `&&` for intersection.

This was a good source on this obscure PostgreSQL feature: https://medium.com/postgres-professional/indexes-in-postgresql-5-gist-86e19781b5db examples are very rare to come by!

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04, PostgreSQL 15.3, Lenovo ThinkPad P51, SSD: Samsung MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7 512GB SSD, 3 GB/s nominal speed.