# How to reference selected bokeh data points

Tags: bokeh

I have created a bokeh figure which uses circle glyphs and which has a lasso_select tool.  This is run from within a ipython notebook.

When I view the figure (which is representing a scatter chart), I select the circles which appear as outliers.

If there a way to reference the selected data from the notebook ?  I suspect that source.selected (where source is the ColumnDataSource used to build the chart) would contain the data I want, however this always is set to:

```
{'0d': {'flag': False, 'indices': []},
 '1d': {'indices': []},
 '2d': {'indices': []}}
```

Perhaps this is not possible ?  Or perhaps I need to use a bokeh-server ?  Or perhaps I should just try to concentrate on a way to dump out the selected data from the javascript ?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to get the index for those outliers and use this index to investigate other sources of data.

Any suggestions or pointers to documentation welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Callbacks](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-selections) This shows an example using the lasso tool.

Comment: I think you link is dead. Please copy-paste the example into your answer.