# Save selected points in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh

I have a Bokeh scatter plot. I want to enable the lasso tool and then save the selected points in a pandas data frame for further processing with python in a Jupyter notebook.

Currently, accessing the `selected` property of `ColumnDataSource` returns an empty structure:

```
{'0d': {'flag': False, 'indices': []},
 '1d': {'indices': []},
 '2d': {'indices': []}}
```

This request is similar to this unanswered [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32909068/895384).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution through the use of Python `Flask` package and by communicating the selected points through the use of AJAX in `customJS` API that supports javascript.