# Plotting very large data on an unstructured grid with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, bigdata

I have a very large, single vector of data (representing 65 million hexagonal cell centroids on a globe), each corresponding to a latitude/longitude point. To my knowledge, the only tool in matplotlib that can work with unstructured data is the tricontour/tricontourf utility (which can also be used with Basemap); however, the triangulation seems to break with such a large dataset.

Is there any other way to plot this data (on a map) without first doing an interpolation (i.e., griddata)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data

Comment: The question may be why would you like to plot 65 million cells if any usual screen can only show 2 million (cubic) pixels?