# paraview: plot data from csv file

Tags: paraview

I am trying to use paraview to plot a xy plot. The plot I want is just a linear relationship between x and y. So I import my data file (data.csv) into paraview. My data is shown below:

```js
X Y
0 0
1 1
2 6
3 8
4 15
```

Then I set the delimiter to " ". After that I can see the data is sorted in x and y column. But I do not find a option to let paraview to plot the data. Any help? Thank you. 
Here is a screenshort of my interface:[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a **Plot Data** filter while you have `data.csv` selected and click *Apply*. a **Line Chart View** will open up, but it won't show anything. In the *Properties* panel, scroll down to the **Series Parameters** subsection. Click on the checkbox to the left of the variable "Y". To put "X" on the x axis, uncheck the *Use Index for XAxis* checkbutton and set the *X Array Name* to "X".