# How to color scatter plot points by the value of a third column in Paraview like gnuplot palette?

Tags: paraview

For example, I generate the data with:

```
i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; do echo "$i,$((2*i)),$((4*i))"; i=$((i+1)); done > main.csv
```

which contains:

```
0,0,0
1,2,4
2,4,8
3,6,12
4,8,16
5,10,20
6,12,24
7,14,28
8,16,32
9,18,36
```

Then for example in gnuplot, I get what I want with `palette`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set terminal png size 1024,1024
set output "main.png"
set datafile separator ","
set key off
plot "main.csv" using 1:2:3 palette pt 7 pointsize 10
```

which gives the desired:

[image]

How to achieve this effect with Paraview?

I managed to make the scatter plot with a Line Chart View, but all points are red like this:

[image]

Also I could not resize the marker sizes, but for that I found an open issue: https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/14169

I am initially learning the GUI for plotting, but if you have a scripting option that is good to know too.

The reason I am looking into Parasol is that I need to plot 10M points interactively, which I have found gnuplot and matplotlib not to handle well, so I'm curious if this VTK-based solution will cut it. More info at: [Large plot: ~20 million samples, gigabytes of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data/55967461#55967461)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, Paraview 5.4.1.

Comment: Hello. I think you cannot do that with the Line Chart View of ParaView. In fact, I think the best way to do that with ParaView is to use the Python View. However, imho, the Python View API is more complicated than that of other plotting tools. I would advise you to use something else, for instance matplotlib if you're OK with python scripting (see for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python)

Comment: Hi @BertrandGazanion I'm OK with scripting, and I know how to do this with Matplotlib. When I asked this, I was mostly interested in evaluating high performance plotting options, since Matplotlib could not handle the 10 million points I had as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data/55967461#55967461 :) GUI setup would be ideal mostly as part of my evaluation for others. If you can make your Paraview solution more precise, do post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @ciro. I didn't realize the performance issue, but know I understand why you want to use ParaView. I am not relevant on the Python View, but as far as I know it relies on matlplotlib. I can show you a solution using glyphs in a 3D render view, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the python script to read the file and display the markers in the ParaView 3D Render View.

```py
import paraview.simple as pvs

# create a new 'CSV Reader'
csvReader = pvs.CSVReader(FileName=['C:\\your_file.csv'])
csvReader.HaveHeaders = 0

# create a new 'Table To Points'
tableToPoints = pvs.TableToPoints(Input=csvReader)
tableToPoints.XColumn = 'Field 0'
tableToPoints.YColumn = 'Field 1'
tableToPoints.ZColumn = 'Field 2'
tableToPoints.KeepAllDataArrays = 1
tableToPoints.a2DPoints = 1

# create a new 'Glyph'
glyph = pvs.Glyph(Input=tableToPoints, GlyphType='Arrow')
glyph.Scalars = ['POINTS', 'Field 0']
glyph.Vectors = ['POINTS', 'None']
glyph.GlyphType = '2D Glyph'
glyph.GlyphType.GlyphType = 'Square'
glyph.GlyphType.Filled = 1
glyph.ScaleMode = 'off'
glyph.ScaleFactor = 1.0
glyph.GlyphMode = 'All Points'
### uncomment to scale markers by 'Field 2'
# glyph1.Scalars = ['POINTS', 'Field 2']
# glyph1.ScaleMode = 'scalar'

# show data in view
renderView = pvs.GetActiveView()
glyphDisplay = pvs.Show(glyph, renderView)
glyphDisplay.Representation = 'Surface'
pvs.ColorBy(glyphDisplay, ('POINTS', 'Field 2'))
glyphDisplay.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView, True)
glyphDisplay.RescaleTransferFunctionToDataRange(True, False)

renderView.Update()
pvs.UpdatePipeline()
renderView.AxesGrid.Visibility = 1
renderView.ResetCamera()
pvs.Render(renderView)
```

And the result:
[image]