# What could I do to build the 3D Bar Chart on my machine using Mayavi?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory, data-visualization, mayavi

Want to build a 3D Bar Chart using Mayavi (on my Asus Laptop Intel CoreTM i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00 GHz with 8 GBs de RAM, Windows 10) using a Jupyter Notebook (on a Python virtualenv) but I'm getting a grey screen.

[Once the data was imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55963606/5675325), I clicked in New > Python 3 and wrote

[image: Mayavi build 3D bar chart]

Used pandas' fast CSV parser, [pandas.read_csv()](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/), and
once I ran line 4, I could see the memory usage increase to 88% of the capable using CleanMem Mini Monitor and got results in less than 1 minute.

Then, to build the [bar chart](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.barchart)

```
df1=df[[0]]
df2=df[[1]]
df3=df[[2]]
mlab.barchart(df1,df2,df3)
```

Unfortunately, I got this MemoryError

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9736b00b5abc> in <module>
      2 df2=df[[1]]
      3 df3=df[[2]]
----> 4 mlab.barchart(df1,df2,df3)

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py in the_function(*args, **kwargs)
     35 
     36     def the_function(*args, **kwargs):
---> 37         return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
     38 
     39     if hasattr(pipeline, 'doc'):

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     80             scene.disable_render = True
     81         # Then call the real logic
---> 82         output = self.__call_internal__(*args, **kwargs)
     83         # And re-enable the rendering, if needed.
     84         if scene is not None:

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py in __call_internal__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1093         """ Override the call to be able to scale automatically the axis.
   1094         """
-> 1095         g = Pipeline.__call_internal__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1096         gs = g.glyph.glyph_source
   1097         # Use a cube source for glyphs.

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py in __call_internal__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     90         the last object created by the pipeline."""
     91         self.store_kwargs(kwargs)
---> 92         self.source = self._source_function(*args, **kwargs)
     93         # Copy the pipeline so as not to modify it for the next call
     94         self.pipeline = self._pipeline[:]

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\sources.py in vertical_vectors_source(*args, **kwargs)
   1356 
   1357     data_source = MVerticalGlyphSource()
-> 1358     data_source.reset(x=x, y=y, z=z, scalars=s)
   1359 
   1360     name = kwargs.pop('name', 'VerticalVectorsSource')

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\sources.py in reset(self, **traits)
    306                 traits['u'] = traits['v'] = np.ones_like(s),
    307                 traits['w'] = s
--> 308         super(MVerticalGlyphSource, self).reset(**traits)
    309 
    310     def _scalars_changed(self, s):

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\sources.py in reset(self, **traits)
    172 
    173         else:
--> 174             points = np.c_[x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()].ravel()
    175             points.shape = (-1, 3)
    176             self.trait_set(points=points, trait_change_notify=False)

c:\infovis\virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    404                 objs[k] = objs[k].astype(final_dtype)
    405 
--> 406         res = self.concatenate(tuple(objs), axis=axis)
    407 
    408         if matrix:

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (153543233, 3) and data type int64
```

And the result was this

[image: Result]

Comment: Are you _sure_ that a bar-chart is what you want? it kinda looks like the x and y coordinates are all 0 or 1, and in any case 100MM items is way too many for a bar chart. If what you really want is a histogram, or to sum the `df[[2]]` values for each x,y pair, then I think you'll want to do some of the data processing yourself before calling the display function.

Comment: Yes a bar-chart is what i want with that data and as many items. It might be a lot to ask for but if it's not possible using mayavi with my conditions, I hope to find other solution where it is possible. If worse comes to worse will have to consider something like sampling.

Comment: Do I read correctly that `(df[[0]], df[[1]])` are your (x,y) coordinates, and `df[[2]]` is the height value? You've got a lot of duplicate (x,y)s; how are you hoping they'll be displayed?

Comment: Right. Here what's in x,y,z didn't matter as the only goal is to check if Mayavi could handle create a bar chart with that many records it into a bar chart. (If meaning was relevant, could have done an average of z and get (x,y) with (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)).

Comment: If you're going to combine values (using average or any other function), then that greatly affects how we approach the memory problem. If you're _not_ going to combine values, then we need a clearer explanation of what you want the output to be. It's unclear how you would physically render a bar chart with a hundred million bars, in 2D _or_ 3D.

Comment: Not gonna do the average (a simple GROUP BY), that would reduce the records to 4. About the output, it was explained already. I'll get a dataset as big where x,y,z makes more sense if you think that helps here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200568/discussion-between-shapeofmatter-and-tiago-martins-peres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to constantly being out-of-memory I had to come up with a way to reduce the amount of data.

Inspired in [Trifacta](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/SS/Overview+of+Sampling#OverviewofSampling-Filter-basedsamples), I've decided to go with *sampling* (create a sample from the CSV file). The following are some of the possible samples I could product

[image: Sampling]

For simplification reasons, decided to go with random samples. [Using Git Bash on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684810/5675325) I just ran a similar command (the number of rows might not be the same as the one used) as

```
shuf -n 10000 BIGFILE.csv > SAMPLEFILE.csv
```

Then the procedure to create the visualization was exactly the same except the name of the file and the result was the following

[image: Mayavi 3D Bar Chart]

[image: Mayavi 3D Bar Chart]

[image: Mayavi 3D Bar Chart]