# How to show the actual axes number values on the Visit plotting program instead of fractions from 0.0 to 1.0?

Tags: visit-llnl

When I do a scatter plot, by default it shows the axis from 0.0 to 1.0 fractions.

For example, the following graph contains a straight line that goes from (0,0) to (10m,10m), but it shows:

[image]

Detailed data generation show at: [Large plot: ~20 million samples, gigabytes of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data/55967461#55967461)

How to make the axes show from 0 to 10 million instead?

The inspiration for this comes [from this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376361/how-to-find-the-sample-points-that-have-statistically-meaningful-large-outlier-r).

Tested in VisIt 2.13.3.

Comment: Meta comment: using a tag like [visit] could be easily misused by other users in future i.e. mistakenly believing it's related to website visits. Is it worth prepending a source to this tag e.g. [llnl-visit]?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I'm not sure what is best to be honest. My gut feeling is keep visit since visit as for website visits should not deserve a tag. It is then a question of how much newbie noise will happen and if it would scare visit devs away. The root problem is that that software is too generically named to start with...

Comment: Just speaking from experience with the daily clean-up of misuse of the [android-studio] tag, very few users read the tag descriptions unfortunately

Comment: @MichaelDodd OK, maybe you are right. I think I'll go for visit-llnl then, so that autocomplete will work a bit better, this should be good enough to avoid mistags I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since scatter plot associates variables of potentially radically different scales, by default, it maps each variable's range into [0,1]. We have [this ticket](https://github.com/visit-dav/visit/issues/3363) for it. You can manually change by going to scatter plot attribute's window and Apperance tab and un-checking the 'Normalize the axes to a cube' option

Comment: Thanks for coming over to answer Mark! I tried it out and it worked perfectly. To be even more explicit for other users, I went under: PlotAtts > Scatter > Apperance > Normalize the axes to a cube. If you have any questions about the Stack Overflow platform, do let me know. The only initial hump is getting 50 reputation to be able to comment, but then it's fine.