# How to plot big csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe with 2232803 rows and two columns `'x'` , `'y'`, I want to draw line plot. x-axis x and y-axis y . I tried some ways but when i plot my computer stuck maybe file is so big , my computer have 8gb RAM. is there anyway to plot that big file

```
i tried this:

plt.plot(df['x'].values,df['y'].values)
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the code, like how you set up your DataFrame dt. Also did you tried the same code with a smaller set like 10 rows?

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/interactive-large-plot-with-20-million-sample-points-and-gigabytes-of-data) is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you plot a random fraction of the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2232803, 2), columns=list('xy'))
df_plot = df.sample(frac=0.01).copy()

plt.plot(df_plot['x'].values, df_plot['y'].values)
```

Comment: random data work fine , when i run my original data have problem , kernel died

Comment: I understand, but the idea is that with a random sample of the data you get a more or else similar graph.

Comment: There are multiple sampling methods as well you can check that.