# Plot large data with vaex

Tags: python, hdf5, large-data, vaex

I've been struggling to create a plot of a csv with millions of lines. I am trying to use the vaex module but I'm stuck..

```
import vaex

# converts and reads large csv into hdf5 format
df = vaex.open("mydir/cov2.csv",  convert='hdf5')
df.head()
```

> ### Output

```
#   chr     pos cov index    
<i style='opacity: 0.6'>0</i>   NC_024468.2 1.34986e+08 6   0     
<i style='opacity: 0.6'>1</i>   NC_024468.2 1.34986e+08 6   1       
<i style='opacity: 0.6'>2</i>   NC_024468.2 1.34986e+08 6   2
```

The csv is converted to hdf5 and loaded, but there now 2 indexes, 1 with a weird HTML formatting.  When I try to plot it like in the [documentation](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=open#vaex.open) and and the solution benchmarked in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/interactive-large-plot-with-20-million-sample-points-and-gigabytes-of-data/55967461#55967461):

```
df.plot_widget(df.pos, df.cov)
```

I get a value error.

```
ValueError: <bound method DataFrame.cov of      
#          chr          pos        cov    index      
0          NC_024468.2  134986302  6      0       
1          NC_024468.2  134986303  6      1      
...        ...          ...        ...    ...      
2,704,117  NC_024468.2  137690419  0      2704117        
2,704,118  NC_024468.2  137690420  0      2704118 > is not of string or Expression type, but <class 'method'>
```

The solution was to change to df.col.cov or df["cov"].  Still, now I get an empty output from the plot_widget method:

```
  PlotTemplate(components={'main-widget': VBox(children=(VBox(children=(Figure(axes=[Axis(color='#666', grid_col…

  Plot2dDefault(w=None, what='count(*)', x='pos', y='cov', z=None)
```

Can anyone help me?

Kind regards,
Ricardo

## EDIT

A sample of the csv data. Column pos increases by 1 on every row (137 Million) and cov is almost always 0, but goes to 1-400 in some areas:

```
chr,pos,cov
NC_024468.2,1,0
NC_024468.2,2,0
NC_024468.2,3,0
.....
NC_024468.2,137690418,7
NC_024468.2,137690419,6
NC_024468.2,137690420,6
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, do you mind to add a sample of your data?

Comment: Hi! I added a sample. I put points  between first 3 rows and last 3 rows. 
I've actually managed to make a plot now with the plot method, but this is only working for a subset of the data, otherwise it crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many issues here:

- Tabulate broke their HTML output: https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/675 . We plan a workaround soon.
- vaex.open calls http://docs.vaex.io/en/latest/api.html#vaex.from_csv which takes copy_index, instead call `vaex.open('...', convert=True, copy_index=False)`. I opened an issue for that https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/754 to change the default.
- df. is a shorthand for df[""] when df. doesn't exist, df.cov already exist :), bad luck.
- The widget issue is a general ipywidgets installation issue, make sure you can display a normal ipywidgets.Button() first.